# Методы сортировки данных

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Не могу разобраться с сортировкой данных на странице. С помощью формы методом POST, на сервер отправляются параметры извлечения данных из mysql(допустим - извлечь строки, в которых `дата бронирования` = 'заданной'). Когда данные получены, пользователь должен иметь возможность их отсортировать по(дате заезда или дате выезда).

Какие существуют способы сортировки данных на странице? Ведь получается, что после того как сервер вернул результат первого запроса, отправляется второй запрос методом GET - уже для сортировки, но тогда сбрасываются параметры первого запроса.

Потратил на поиски кучу времени, но так и не нашёл ответа!

Answer (score 1):

А ты не сбрасывай параметры запроса, направляй ещё раз и добавляй ORDER BY. Но это если дёрганье базы на каждый запрос является приемлемым по нагрузке.

Comment: Записей будет извлекаться не много. Примерно до 50 полей. Вот как раз и интересует, как добиться того, чтобы не сбрасывать параметры запроса.

Comment: Самый примитивный вариант: сохранить в скрытые поля формы, а заголовки столбцов, которые используются для выбора сортировки, сделать самбитами, каждому дать свой name, и по нему смотреть, который из них нажат.